# fetch values in array using angular.foreach to loop object values

Tags: angularjs

I am looping an object to get values for a particular set (here it is _source). Here in the example I would like to loop the object and get the _source values from the object and push in array.
 I am using angular.forEach for this. However when I use this function I am not getting an array. I am looking for an output like:

```
myarr[0] = [value1:0, value2: "2", value3:"MON"]
myarr[1] = [value1:1, value2:"3", value3: "MON1"]
```

My code:

```
Mysvc.getSourceValues()
            .success(function (data) {

                srcobj= data.hits.kal;
                angular.forEach(srcobj, function(value, key) {

                    var sourcevalues= value._source;
                    //this.push(key + ': ' + value);
                });



            })
            .error(function (error) {
                $log.info("Unable to load values");
            })
```

My srcobjdata:

```
{

        "kal": [
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 0,
                    "value2": "2",
                    "value3": "MON"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "logw-2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 1,
                    "value2": "3",
                    "value3": "MON1"
                },
                "sort": [
                    2
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log-2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                   "value1": 3,
                    "value2": "265",
                    "value3": "MON2"
                },
                "sort": [
                    3
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                   "value1": 4,
                    "value2": "5",
                    "value3": "MON5"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            {
                "_index": "log2015.18",
                "_type": "MT_DETAIL",
                "_sc": null,
                "_source": {
                    "value1": 7,
                    "value2": "3",
                    "value3": "MON8"
                },
                "sort": [
                    1
                ]
            }
        ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.forEach(srcObj, function(value, key) {                    
    angular.forEach(value, function(valueI) {
        console.log(valueI._source);
    })
});
```

Try this. You value gets an array of values, and then you would have to loop through each of the array elements, which will contain the source property.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mysvc.getSourceValues()
.success(function(data) {
     var myarray = [];

    srcobj = data.hits.kal;

    angular.forEach(data.kal, function(value, key){
        myarray.push(value._source);
    });
})
.error(function(error) {
    $log.info("Unable to load values");
})
```